# Bad Redirect On Create Method - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am trying to change the redirect when I create a listing, but I keep getting a `No route matches {:action=>"manage_photos", :controller=>"listings"} missing required keys: [:id]`. What am I missing? My route is nested and there is a `manage_photos` method in my controller. Not sure where to go from here.

routes.rb

```
resources :listings do
  member do
    get 'like'
    get 'unlike'
    get 'duplicate'
    get 'gallery'
    delete 'gallery' => 'listings#clear_gallery'
    get 'manage_photos'
    get 'craigslist'
    get "add_to_collection"
    get 'request_photos'
    get 'rsvp'
  end
end
```

rake routes:

```
manage_photos_listing GET  /listings/:id/manage_photos(.:format)  listings#manage_photos
```

listings_controller:

create method:

```
def create
  @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @listing.save
      format.html { redirect_to manage_photos_listing_path, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @listing, status: :created, location: @listing }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new", notice: "Correct the mistakes below to create the new listing" }
      format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

manage_photos method:

```
def manage_photos
  @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
end
```

error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a nested resource you have to add the id of the parent element. Try:

`manage_photo_listing(@listing)`

so it can actually use the id of `@listing` and build the route

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could do that in the controller. Thanks for the help, works great!